# Django returns Segmentation fault (core dumped) in AIX

Tags: python-2.7, aix, coredump, django-1.8

I installed Python 2.7.10 with a rpm file in AIX7.1.

The installation seems complete without any problem.

As next step, I installed `pip` package and `Django(1.8.3)` through pip and then I tested the Django with the below.

**Server**

```
django-admin startproject djangoTest # create basic django project
manage.py runserver                  # run django test server
```

**Client**

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8000                # connect to the django test
server GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1 # send GET request
```

As result of that, django test server is killed returning `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

The core file show like the below .

```
dbx python2.7 core

Segmentation fault in posix_kill at line 4360 in file "" ($t1)
couldn't read "./Modules/posixmodule.c"

(dbx) where
posix_kill(self = (nil), args = 0x30ec5198), line 4360 in "posixmodule.c"
PyCFunction_Call(func = 0x3006a0b8, arg = 0x30ec5198, kw = (nil)), line 81 in "methodobject.c"
unnamed block in ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff1a4b4, oparg = 2), line 4035 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff1a4b4, oparg = 2), line 4035 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff1a4b4, oparg = 2), line 4035 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed0c08, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed0c08, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30ec5c48, globals = 0x30eb5b28, locals = (nil), args = 0x30ed0a68, argcount = 3, kws = 0x30ed0a74, kwcount = 0, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
fast_function(func = 0x30ec2388, pp_stack = 0x2ff1b234, n = 3, na = 3, nk = 0), line 4131 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff1b234, oparg = 3), line 4056 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed0918, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed0918, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30ec5808, globals = 0x30eb5b28, locals = (nil), args = 0x30ed5720, argcount = 3, kws = 0x30ed572c, kwcount = 0, defs = 0x30ea9114, defcount = 2, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
fast_function(func = 0x30ec2428, pp_stack = 0x2ff1bfb4, n = 3, na = 3, nk = 0), line 4131 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff1bfb4, oparg = 3), line 4056 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed55d8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed55d8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30e58e48, globals = 0x30e5abc8, locals = (nil), args = 0x30d133b4, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30ecdb84, kwcount = 11, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
function_call(func = 0x30dce7e8, arg = 0x30d133a8, kw = 0x30ec9cd8), line 526 in "funcobject.c"
unnamed block in PyObject_Call(func = 0x30dce7e8, arg = 0x30d133a8, kw = 0x30ec9cd8), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
PyObject_Call(func = 0x30dce7e8, arg = 0x30d133a8, kw = 0x30ec9cd8), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
ext_do_call(func = 0x30dce7e8, pp_stack = 0x2ff1cd4c, flags = 2, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4348 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed6458, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ed6458, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30e57358, globals = 0x30e5abc8, locals = (nil), args = 0x30df64c4, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30ecd644, kwcount = 11, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
function_call(func = 0x30a9c0b8, arg = 0x30df64b8, kw = 0x30eced38), line 526 in "funcobject.c"
unnamed block in PyObject_Call(func = 0x30a9c0b8, arg = 0x30df64b8, kw = 0x30eced38), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
PyObject_Call(func = 0x30a9c0b8, arg = 0x30df64b8, kw = 0x30eced38), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
ext_do_call(func = 0x30a9c0b8, pp_stack = 0x2ff1dafc, flags = 3, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4348 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ecffc8, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ecffc8, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x3049e388, globals = 0x3048ba88, locals = (nil), args = 0x30d4a294, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30ec2c24, kwcount = 11, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
function_call(func = 0x305018a8, arg = 0x30d4a288, kw = 0x30e58548), line 526 in "funcobject.c"
unnamed block in PyObject_Call(func = 0x305018a8, arg = 0x30d4a288, kw = 0x30e58548), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
PyObject_Call(func = 0x305018a8, arg = 0x30d4a288, kw = 0x30e58548), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
ext_do_call(func = 0x305018a8, pp_stack = 0x2ff1e8ac, flags = 3, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4348 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ec8c48, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30ec8c48, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30e502e8, globals = 0x30e5abc8, locals = (nil), args = 0x30d119f4, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30eceb64, kwcount = 11, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
function_call(func = 0x30a9c018, arg = 0x30d119e8, kw = 0x30ecdeb8), line 526 in "funcobject.c"
unnamed block in PyObject_Call(func = 0x30a9c018, arg = 0x30d119e8, kw = 0x30ecdeb8), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
PyObject_Call(func = 0x30a9c018, arg = 0x30d119e8, kw = 0x30ecdeb8), line 2529 in "abstract.c"
ext_do_call(func = 0x30a9c018, pp_stack = 0x2ff1f65c, flags = 3, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4348 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30e42fe8, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30e42fe8, throwflag = 0), line 2720 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x3049d738, globals = 0x3048ba88, locals = (nil), args = 0x3014854c, argcount = 2, kws = 0x30148554, kwcount = 0, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
fast_function(func = 0x30501858, pp_stack = 0x2ff203f4, n = 2, na = 2, nk = 0), line 4131 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff203f4, oparg = 1), line 4056 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x301483f8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x301483f8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30204088, globals = 0x301da448, locals = (nil), args = 0x30145b38, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30145b3c, kwcount = 0, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
fast_function(func = 0x30208018, pp_stack = 0x2ff21174, n = 1, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4131 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff21174, oparg = 0), line 4056 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x301459f8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x301459f8, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30204368, globals = 0x301da448, locals = (nil), args = 0x30145564, argcount = 1, kws = 0x30145568, kwcount = 0, defs = 0x30200684, defcount = 1, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
fast_function(func = 0x30207e88, pp_stack = 0x2ff21ef4, n = 1, na = 1, nk = 0), line 4131 in "ceval.c"
ceval.call_function(pp_stack = 0x2ff21ef4, oparg = 1), line 4056 in "ceval.c"
unnamed block in PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30145428, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(f = 0x30145428, throwflag = 0), line 2681 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCodeEx(co = 0x30141da8, globals = 0x300543a8, locals = 0x300543a8, args = (nil), argcount = 0, kws = (nil), kwcount = 0, defs = (nil), defcount = 0, closure = (nil)), line 3267 in "ceval.c"
PyEval_EvalCode(co = 0x30141da8, globals = 0x300543a8, locals = 0x300543a8), line 669 in "ceval.c"
run_mod(mod = 0x30146558, filename = "manage.py", globals = 0x300543a8, locals = 0x300543a8, flags = 0x2ff22a34, arena = 0x30054f78), line 1371 in "pythonrun.c"
PyRun_FileExFlags(fp = 0xf0870d30, filename = "manage.py", start = 257, globals = 0x300543a8, locals = 0x300543a8, closeit = 1, flags = 0x2ff22a34), line 1357 in "pythonrun.c"
PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags(fp = 0xf0870d30, filename = "manage.py", closeit = 1, flags = 0x2ff22a34), line 949 in "pythonrun.c"
PyRun_AnyFileExFlags(fp = 0xf0870d30, filename = "manage.py", closeit = 1, flags = 0x2ff22a34), line 753 in "pythonrun.c"
Py_Main(argc = 3, argv = 0x2ff22c00), line 642 in "main.c"
python.main(argc = 3, argv = 0x2ff22c00), line 23 in "python.c"
```

What is the problem and how to fix it ?

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: `couldn't read "./Modules/posixmodule.c"` : edit your Q to show output of `ls -l  "./Modules/posixmodule.c"` assuming you know what is the parent path to `./Modules`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall the python upgrading to version `2.7.11` as the same way(`rpm`).

Surprisingly, It works fine.

I don't understand how a minor version make this big change on `AIX`.